# Ajax Submits automatically be invoked in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird problem.. This is my jquery code

```
  $("#btnRate").click(function (e) {

        alert("tık");
        e.preventDefault();

        var electionId = '@Model.ElectionId';
        var profileId = '@Model.ProfileId';

        $.ajax({
           url:  "Profile/Vote",  // '@Html.Action("Vote","Profile")',
          //  data: { electionId: electionId, profileId: profileId },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",

            error: function (error) {
                alert('An error occured, please try again! ');
            },

            success: function (data) {


                if (data != null && data.success) {
                    alert("s1");
                    alert(data.url);
                    alert("s2");
                    window.location = data.url;

                } else {


                    alert('An error occured, please try again. ');

                }


            }
        });

        return false;


    });
```

and this is the html side code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input id="btnRate" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Vote !" />
    </div>
</div>
```

when the detail form is loaded, automatically be invoked as clicked btnRate button. But i do not click..

and this is vote action in profilecontroller

```
//  [HttpPost]
    [ChildActionOnly] 
    public JsonResult Vote() //(int profileId, int electionId)
    {
        EvoteServicesProviderClient service = new EvoteServicesProviderClient();
  //    var result=  service.createPolls(electionId, profileId);
    //    if(result ==1)
      //      return Json(new { success = true, url = "/Home/ProfileStatistic?electionId=" + electionId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       // else
         //   return Json(new { success = false, url = "/Home/ProfileStatistic?electionId=" + electionId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


       return null;
    }
```

even i do not click, vote function is invoked by ajax.. What is the reason?

edit: this is exception

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: make sure you are **not** using `@Html.Action()` in ajax request url because this problem occurs when we use `@Html.Action` instead try using `@Url.Action`

Comment: Its marked with `[ChildActionOnly]` so it can't be called by the ajax method, so your calling it somewhere else.

Comment: @Kartikeya, I use /Post/.." is it the same?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I just added the childactiononly, but with it or without it, the result is the same, i mean, it always be invoked. and i am sure that i havent called it somewhere else

Comment: Is the $("#btnRate").click binding done within a 'document ready'?

Comment: If you have the `[ChildActionOnly]` then the only way this can be called is if you have `@Html.Action()` somewhere else in your view (its not being called from the ajax method)

Comment: @Zaphod, yes the code is like that   $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnRate").click(function(e) {

Comment: @StephenMuecke, but i am sure that i havent called it somewhere else. I searched and no result.. because i already have just created..

Comment: Is this the only script in the view? Are you triggering the event from some other code?

Comment: I am actually calling this http://localhost:1880/Profile/Detail?profileId=1&electionId=20 but it automatically be invoked vote.. if i delete ajax part, then detail action is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.. very interesting ..
 I just deleted the comment 
 // '@Html.Action("Vote","Profile")',

and it works good now.. 
 this is the last part..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnRate").click(function(e) {

        alert("geldi");

        alert("tık");
        e.preventDefault();

        var electionId = '@Model.ElectionId';
        var profileId = '@Model.ProfileId';

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Vote","Profile")',  
            data: { electionId: electionId, profileId: profileId },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",

            error: function (error) {
                alert('An error occured, please try again! ');
            },

            success: function (data) {


                if (data != null && data.success) {
                    alert("s1");
                    alert(data.url);
                    alert("s2");
                    window.location = data.url;

                } else {


                    alert('An error occured, please try again. ');

                }


            }
        });

        return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: Since `var electionId = '@Model.ElectionId';` and `var profileId = '@Model.ProfileId';` will only ever be the values that were initially passed to the view, what on earth is the point of this code?